# How to skip or put None if the value Field missing in dictionary while searching with two files python

Tags: python-3.x

I have two files `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`, where `file1.txt` contains user names only and `file2.txt`  conatins users and and user group but here in `file2.txt`  some of the users missing group names.

file1.txt:

```
user1
user2
user3
user4
```

-- snipped --

file2.txt:

```
user1 WFO
user2 ITO
user3 
user4 WFO
user5 WFO
user6
user7 SPP
```

-- snipped --

I have tried below code which works fine if `file2.txt` has the both key and values as i using dictionary to evaludate and match but fails when `file2.txt` dont have value and will through index error.

```
usr=[]
with open('file.txt','r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        line=line.strip()
        usr.append(line)
#print(usr)
bus={}
with open('fle2.txt','r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        line=line.split()
        bus[line[0]]=line[1]
        for key in usr:
            key.rstrip()
            if key in bus:
                print(key,bus[key])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./File_compare.py", line 12, in <module>
    bus[line[0]]=line[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I need the users and values for `file1.txt` if they are in `file2.txt`

Comment: @9769953, yes correct, are you saying you only need the user (names) that have a group defined? Yes , but we need to check against the users in file1.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following?

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

users = set()
with open("list1.txt") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        user = line.strip()
        if user:
            users.add(user)

groups = defaultdict(set)
with open("list2.txt") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        try:
            user, group = line.strip().split(maxsplit=1)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        if user.strip() in users:
            groups[user].add(group)

pprint(groups)
```

This does two (extra) things:

- only adds a group to a user that is in "file1.txt" (this appears to be a requirement from a comment)
- allows multiple groups per user

---

As an example, taking your input files and extending the latter with one entry:

list1.txt:

```
user1
user2
user3
user4
```

list2.txt:

```
user1 WFO
user2 ITO
user3
user4 WFO
user5 WFO
user6
user7 SPP
user1 ITO
```

Both example files are complete, that is, not "snipped".
"list2.txt" contains "user1" twice, once with group "WFO" and once with group "ITO".

Running the above code produces:

```
defaultdict(<class 'set'>,
            {'user1': {'ITO', 'WFO'},
             'user2': {'ITO'},
             'user4': {'WFO'}})
```

"user5", "user6" and "user7" are not present, since these are not in "list1.txt".

"user1" has two groups, while all other users have one group only.

Note that I have used `set`s instead of `list`s, so that accidental double entries in the input files are automatically avoided in the result.

Comment: thnx for the time & efforts paid, i'have marked the solution. However, my ouput does not produce dict like output.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried Below which is working, However, i'm looking if there is much elegant way to achieve this.

```
 #!/usr/bin/python3
import re

usr=[]
bus={}

with open('file1.txt','r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        line=line.strip()
        usr.append(line)
with open('file2.txt','r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        pat_match =  re.match("\w+\s+\w+",line)
        if pat_match:
            line=line.split()
            bus[line[0]]=line[1]
for key in usr:
    key.rstrip()
    if key in bus:
        print("{0:<15}{1:<20}".format(key,bus[key]))
```

This prints:

```
$ ./userData.py
user1   WFO
user2   ITO
user4   WFO
```